# "Einen Schritt gehen" vs "einen Schritt machen"

Tags: meaning

> Sie will den nächsten Schritt in ihrer Karriere gehen.

vs

> Sie will den nächsten Schritt in ihrer Karriere machen.

Is there a difference in meaning between the two sentences? Which sentence would you say sounds more natural?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think both sentences are perfectly fine, and I'd say I've come across each of them, yet 'einen Schritt machen' slightly more often.

If one wants to find a distinction, the only one I see or perceive is that "den nächsten Schritt gehen" sounds ever so slightly more elevated or formal than "den nächsten Schritt machen" - but it's a tiny nuance at best to my ears.

Answer (score 3):

Both variants are possible but i would ever so slightly prefer "Schritt machen" over "Schritt gehen" in this case: "gehen" is a specific way of making a step (i.e. another would be "laufen") and in the context of your sentence - you talk about a career - the "step" is a metaphorical one and "gehen", "laufen" or similar specific physical activities to undertake it seem to be less suitable than the more general "machen" IMHO.